# Form of the particular solution for $g(t)=3\sin(2t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the "proper" form of the particular solution for
$y''+4y=3\sin(2t)$?

When I use

$Y(t)=A\cos(2t)+B\sin(2t)$,

I am not able to solve for the coefficient
after subtitution of the differential equation for $Y''(t)$ and $Y(t)$.

I tried to multiply with an additional $t$, that is, I let

$Y(t)=At\cos(2t)+Bt\sin(2t)$,

but I still got the wrong answer...

Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first guess failed because your guess is the solution to the homogeneous equation
$$ y''+4y=0. $$
Your second attempt should work just fine. Let $y_p(t)=At\cos(2t) + Bt\sin(2t)$, computing its first and second derivatives yields:
\begin{align*}
y_p'(t) & = A[\cos(2t) -2t\sin(2t)] + B[\sin(2t) + 2t\cos(2t)]\\
& = A\cos(2t) + B\sin(2t) +2Bt\cos(2t) -2At\sin(2t).\\
y_p''(t) & = -2A\sin(2t) + 2B\cos(2t) +2B[\cos(2t) - 2t\sin(2t)] -2A[\sin(2t) + 2t\cos(2t)]\\
& = 4B\cos(2t) -4A\sin(2t) -4At\cos(2t) -4Bt\sin(2t).
\end{align*}
Substituting $y_p''$ and $y_p$ into the ODE $y''+4y=3\sin(2t)$ gives
$$ 4B\cos(2t) - 4A\sin(2t) = 3\sin(2t). $$
Comparing coefficients of $\cos(2t)$ and $\sin(2t)$ on both sides, we see that $B=0$ and $A=-\dfrac{3}{4}$. Thus, the particular solution is $y_p(t)=-\dfrac{3}{4}t\cos(2t)$.

Comment: Something has gone wrong there. The particular solution is $-\frac{3}{4}t\cos2t$.

Comment: Thanks for catching that (:

Comment: @ Chee Han and @almagest: Thanks for helping out :)